# AngularJS dynamic routes and templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to setup a wildcard or dynamic routing with templates, for example:

`/page/test` would resolve the template in `page/test.tpl.html`

I have the following and I've tried some variations appending `.tpl.html`, but it doesn't seem to work right.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

```
angular.module('page', []).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/page/:route', {
      templateUrl: function($routeParams) { 
        return $routeParams; 
      },
      controller: 'PageController'
    });

  }])
  .controller('PageController', ['$scope', 
    function ($scope) {

  }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the dynamic values of route by $routeprovider.route. Try the below,

```
$routeProvider.when('/page/:route', {
          templateUrl: function($routeParams) { 
            return '/page/'+$routeParams.route+'.tpl.html'; 
          },
          controller: 'PageController'
        });
```

Comment: This should works, but also needs the module ngRoute, as David Sung Lee said in his answer.

Comment: It would help if you can provide some explanation to your answer

Comment: Yep, this works perfect, I didn't have the `.route` in my previous test. `ngRoute` I have in another module that inherits this one, so all good.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 'ngRoute' in the module definition.  I would also check your index.html to see if you're loading the angular-route.js module.

```
angular.module('page', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
```

See: [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Answer (score 0):

I think ngRoute is not good for dynamic routing. you can use ui route and lazy loading approach.

Please see the example https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs-optimisation/tree/master/client/src/app